# CopyTo in google apps script won't finish its execution on more than 1000 rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using `originalRange.copyTo(rangeToCopyTo)` to basically pull down functions for the number of rows of data I have. CopyTo works fine for a smaller number of rows of data but when I get to large reports that have 1000 results it doesn't finish. It looks like it pulls down the data but it doesn't actually fill in the cells correctly, they are left blank. I have tried using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` but that doesn't work and I have also tried making the program sleep directly after the call with `Utilities.sleep(some value in ms)`. I have been stuck for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
[image: Picture of spreadsheet functionality I'm trying to create]

The red box is my original range those cells are full of formulas that reference the data to the left (I had to scroll over so some of the data is off screen to the left along with the row numbers). The blue box is the range I drag down to the bottom (there are 1000 rows so just imagine the blue box extending down for 1000 rows). The green line on the right side of column G starts out at only 3 rows long since this is duplicated from a template sheet. So since I see the line has been extended all the way to the bottom I know the function is almost working it's just not filling in all the formulas I need it to before moving on to the next sheet so it gets skipped and left blank.

```js
function autoFillReport(sheet) {
  var rowsInSheet = sheet.getRange("A5:A").getLastRow();
  
  //get last row number of data
  var labelColumn = sheet.getRange("A5:A").getValues();
  var lastRowOfData;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsInSheet - 4; i++) {
    if (labelColumn[i].toString().length < 1) {
      lastRowOfData = i + 4;
      break;
    };
  };
  
  //get last row number of rank formulas
  var trafficRankColumn = sheet.getRange("H5:H").getValues();
  var lastRowOfFormulas;
  for (i = 0; i < rowsInSheet - 4; i++) {
    if (trafficRankColumn[i].toString().length < 1) {
      lastRowOfFormulas = i + 4;
      break;
    };
  };
  
  //autofill remaining rows with rank formulas
  if (lastRowOfFormulas < lastRowOfData) {
    var originalRange = sheet.getRange("G5:L5");
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange("G5:L" + (lastRowOfData));
   // originalRange.copyTo(targetRange);
    originalRange.autoFill(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
    runRemainingFormulas = true;
  };
};
```

Comment: Have your tired break them into 100 rows and looping 10 times to get all 1000 rows? Also, can you share an example sheet?

Comment: Ok I just updated it. Also no I have not tried breaking them into 100 row increments. I would like to get it working this way to save time since there is a 6 min execution limit and I want to get as many reports done in each execution as possible.

Comment: Edit in your code. Odds are your loop can be improved.

Comment: I'm not looping anything right now I'm using the copyTo function in google apps script. I am going to try looping though since it seems to be something possibly with the copyTo function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to copy the formulas down? Try this

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET');
  var range = sheet.getRange(5, 7, 3, 6);
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(5, 7, sheet.getLastRow(), 6);
  range.autoFill(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

This should copy the formulas all the way down to the last row of your sheet. The arguments that the 'getRange()' method accepts represent the coordinates of the upper left cell (G7 - row 5, column 7) and the lowermost right cell (last row, column 6).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Doing it this way, while it works for smaller amounts of data like the copyTo method, yields the same result.

Comment: In my case, it populates 2000 rows almost instantly, so the issue must be your formula or something else. What is your formula? Does it make  calls to some external service?

Comment: It's 6 different formulas total, each cell has it's own formula, that references values from the sheet. The formulas are pretty big here's one. 
`=IF($E5<$O$46,1, IF($E5<$O$45,2, IF($E5<$O$44,3, IF($E5<$O$43,4, IF($E5<$O$42,5, IF($E5<$O$41,6, IF($E5<$O$40,7, IF($E5<$O$39,8, IF($E5<$O$38,9,10)))))))))`

Comment: I used your formula and again, it populated 2000 rows in less than a second. Could you perhaps share your code? Also, could you confirm you are not using Utilities.sleep() anywhere?

Comment: I added the function at the bottom of my post

Comment: I don't have Utilities.sleep but I am using SpreadsheetApp.flush() in various places in the script.

Comment: I could be wrong, but if you are trying to get last rows for 2 separate columns, doing this in a loop seems like an overkill. Basically, you are looping over the entire dataset from beginning to end just to determine its length. This can be substituted by  "var values = range.getValues(); var lastRow = values.length + 5" (to account for 4 header rows and zero-indexed values array). For column H, this is not significant, but it's not immediately clear how many values are there in column A.  Also, since this is a partial script, the issue could be lurking somewhere else

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help it is now working great! Also google has a great tool for finding the last row with data in it, sheet.getLastRow() so it was even more simple than using the values to get the length

Comment: Cool, glad I could help