# How do you copy more than 1000 rows to a new Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have some code that pulls a range of data from a source sheet in another file and copies it to a new sheet in the current file.  It used to work but now that the source range is over 1000 rows, the copy fails entirely and without error (the copy doesn't occur and the code moves along).  It seems as though it's because my destination sheet only has 1000 rows and trying to copy something larger than that causes it to fail.

The "Execution Transcript" doesn't give me any insight as to why it fails.  As a test, I shortened the source data to less than 1000 rows and it worked again.

The chunk of my code that copies the range is this:

```
// COPY DATA FROM SOURCE SPREADSHEET TO TEMP SHEET IN ACTIVE SPREADSHEET  
var SRange = source_s.getDataRange();      
var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();  
var SData = SRange.getValues();  
temp_s.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
```

*temp_s* is the destination sheet.
*source_s* is the source sheet.

I suppose either of two solutions could work so I could get more than 1000 rows copied to my destination sheet:

1. Use a type of copy function that will automatically resize the sheet to handle the size of the range, or
2. Find a way to extend the sheet's size prior to the copy, similar to the "Add 1000 more rows at bottom" function you normally see at the bottom of a google sheet.

Comment: Problem solved.  I had declared a range on the destination sheet to be simply "A:J" or whatever column range, which would select all the rows for those two columns.  That in effect made it A1:J1000.  That works if your source is less than 1000 rows, but once the source is bigger than the desination, it fails.     TO SOLVE IT I found the last row of the source data using `lastrow = source_s.getLastRow()` and then named my destination range as `"A1:+J"+lastrow`.  The copy worked.

Comment: I can't explain why Google stopped at 1000 (and I'd love to see your spreadsheet and code to find out why). I can think of a few things like arrayformula, other scripts, but that's just speculating. This topic addressed a similar question [CopyTo in google apps script won't finish its execution on more than 1000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49417049/1330560) with a satisfactory outcome. Anyway, a variation on your destination range might be to declare the range entirely by `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` or even `copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)`.

Comment: You might care to answer your own question. Remember that someone else might have just the same problem one day and it is much easier to find a solution when there is an answer, then to crawl though the comments.

Answer (score 1):

*I posted this as a comment, but it should probably go as an answer too.*

I had declared the range on the destination sheet to be simply `"A:J"` which would select all the rows for those two columns. That in effect made it `A1:J1000`. That works if your source is less than 1000 rows, but once the source is bigger than the desination, it fails.

TO SOLVE IT I found the last row of the source data using `lastrow = source_s.getLastRow()` and then named my destination range as `"A1:+J"+lastrow`. The copy worked.